# How to convert a float scale to long scale?

Tags: java, android

I have two scales,one is x-value scale,with float values which starts from minimum x value and ends at maximum x value.I call these values as min_x and max_x.
I have another scale  with long value which starts from 0 and ends at maximum time value,i call it max_tim value.

how do i convert a float xvalue into corresponding long time value?

I have tried something on android studio but i am getting incorrect values.

```
private long max_tim,tim;
private float min_x,max_x,x_val;

tim=((long)((x_val-min_x)/(max_x-min_x)))*max_tim;
```

I have got correct values of tim for max_x and min_x but not for the values in between.I think i have correct logic but think its faulty typecasting.Please help me out.

Comment: Don't use IDE tags (or any tags) just because you use it. Tags are for subjects that are relevant to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
float range = max_x - min_x;  // get the absolute range of the first scale
float offset = x_val - min_x; // normalize the value on the first scale to the absolute range
tim = (long)((offset*max_tim)/range); // convert to the new scale, which is already in absolute values
```

For example, if your x-value scale is in farenheit and ranges from 32.0 - 212.0.  And your "long scale" is in centigrade from 0-100.  And you wanted to convert 50 degrees Farenheit to centigrade

```
range = 212-32; // 180
offset = 50-32; // 18 
tim = (18*100)/180 = 10;
```

50°F == 10° C

Comment: I have the same logic but its not working out in java/android studio.I think that it is something to do with typecasting

Comment: @user428665 - Notice that my code above is multiplying **before** it does any division. I also updated the answer to show the long cast.  The cast is the **last** thing to do to get the best accuracy and to avoid integer division clamping.

Comment: thank you very much,you were correct multiplying before division was the answer.

Comment: Excellent. If you found the answer useful, don't forget to upvote and/or "accept" it.